# Microsoft WORD 2010 - apostrophe issues

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm writing a series of emails for a client, and when they sent the email for proofing, where I should see "don't" I see:

Donâ€™t

They tell me it's a matter of changing the font I'm using in WORD to create the docs. I'm STUMPED. How can I create docs that won't result in that gosh-awful sight?! What changes do I need to make?

Comment: This is more of a hack than an answer, but try this: go into “Word Options” → “Proofing”, click on “AutoCorrect Options”, go to the “AutoFormat As You Type” tab, and turn off the “ “Straight quotes” with “smart quotes” ” option.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with turning off the smart quotes, per Scott's comment and the following article:  http://ask-leo.com/why_do_i_get_odd_characters_instead_of_quotes_in_my_documents.html